# Spring batch 2.2.0 not writing data to file

Tags: spring-batch, flat-file

We have a spring batch application which inserts data into few tables and then selects data from few tables based on multiple business conditions and writes the data in feed file(flat text file). The application while run generates empty feed file only with headers and no data. The select query when ran separately in SQL developer runs for 2 hours and fetches the data (approx 50 million records). We are using the below components in the application JdbcCursorItemReader and FlatFileWrtier. Below is the configuration details used.

```
maxBatchSize=100 
fileFetchSize=1000
commitInterval=10000
```

There are no errors or exceptions while the application is run. Wanted to know if we are missing anything here or is any spring batch components not properly used.Any pointers in this regard would be really helpful.

Comment: Spring Batch 2.2.0 is not supported anymore. If you have a [minimal example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) that reproduces the issue with the latest 4.2.4 we can dig deeper.

Comment: Unfortunately as of now we are not considering upgrading spring batch version. Is there any changes required to the above configuration parameters? Or any other parameter like fetchMaxRows required in this scenario?